# Scaling numbers taken from a different font?

Tags: fonts, numbering, scaling

I wonder if i can re-scale numbers from different font. For example i took times numbers using `txr`. Can i re-scale these numbers.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\DeclareSymbolFont{txnumbers}{T1}{txr}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{txnumbers}{bold}{T1}{txr}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{0}\mathalpha{txnumbers}{"30}
\DeclareMathSymbol{1}\mathalpha{txnumbers}{"31}
\DeclareMathSymbol{2}\mathalpha{txnumbers}{"32}
\DeclareMathSymbol{3}\mathalpha{txnumbers}{"33}
\DeclareMathSymbol{4}\mathalpha{txnumbers}{"34}
\DeclareMathSymbol{5}\mathalpha{txnumbers}{"35}
\DeclareMathSymbol{6}\mathalpha{txnumbers}{"36}
\DeclareMathSymbol{7}\mathalpha{txnumbers}{"37}
\DeclareMathSymbol{8}\mathalpha{txnumbers}{"38}
\DeclareMathSymbol{9}\mathalpha{txnumbers}{"39}
\begin{document}
I want to scale this numbers: $1234567890$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you really want to mix Times numbers with Computer Modern? It's like putting parmesan cheese on “spaghetti alle vongole” (spaghetti with clams, in English): a mortal sin.

Comment: No, of course. I just tried to tell what i need. I will try this for newtx-libertine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming this is just an exercise, the trick is to load define a font specification for the font you intend to use.

We can read the file `t1txr.fd` and use the data slightly modified:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{txrnumbers}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{txrnumbers}{m}{n}{<->s*[1.2]t1xr}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{txrnumbers}{b}{n}{<->s*[1.2]t1xb}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{txnumbers}{T1}{txrnumbers}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{txnumbers}{bold}{T1}{txrnumbers}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{0}\mathalpha{txnumbers}{"30}
\DeclareMathSymbol{1}\mathalpha{txnumbers}{"31}
\DeclareMathSymbol{2}\mathalpha{txnumbers}{"32}
\DeclareMathSymbol{3}\mathalpha{txnumbers}{"33}
\DeclareMathSymbol{4}\mathalpha{txnumbers}{"34}
\DeclareMathSymbol{5}\mathalpha{txnumbers}{"35}
\DeclareMathSymbol{6}\mathalpha{txnumbers}{"36}
\DeclareMathSymbol{7}\mathalpha{txnumbers}{"37}
\DeclareMathSymbol{8}\mathalpha{txnumbers}{"38}
\DeclareMathSymbol{9}\mathalpha{txnumbers}{"39}
\begin{document}
I want to scale the numbers: $1234567890$
\end{document}
```

I use a different name for the font family, so this will not interfere with possible other uses of `txr`; the most important thing is to add the scaling specification (see `fntguide.pdf` for more information). Of course, `1.2` is exaggerated to illustrate the effect.

[image]